# Orthonormal eigenvectors of the all 1 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb{1}$ denote the all-ones vector. Then $M=\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^\top$ is a rank $1$ matrix with one non-zero eigenvalue: $n$, and the rest $n-1$ eigenvalues are $0$. The eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $n$ is $\mathbb{1}$.

What I want to find now is a set of orthogonal eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues $n$ and $0$. Clearly, any vector with the sum of entries $= 0$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $0$. Can we have a set of $n$ orthogonal vectors
$$v_1=\mathbb{1},\; v_2,\; \ldots,\; v_n$$
such that all of them are eigenvectors of $M$?

Comment: The $0$-eigenspace has dimension $n-1$ and certainly has an orthogonal basis of $n-1$ vectors.

Comment: @markvs Yes but I can't seem to construct such a basis.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305138/do-j-the-all-ones-matrix-of-even-order-always-have-eigenvectors-consisting-o

Comment: Find any basis then use Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Hint: $(1,-1,0,0)$, $(1,1,-2,0)$, and $(1,1,1,-3)$ are orthogonal. Generalize and normalize.